# How to determine the type of incoming call (video/audio) in JsSIP?

Tags: reactjs, sip, jssip

I am working with JsSIP for handling WebRTC calls in my application, and I'm trying to distinguish between incoming video and audio calls. I have implemented the following code snippet to handle incoming and outgoing calls:

```
 const outgoingCall = async (session: RTCSession) => {
    attachLocalStream(session, "videoRemote");
    session.on("progress", () => {
      setOutgoingCall(true);
    });
    session.on("connecting", () => {
      console.log("outgoingCall call is in connecting ...");
    });
    session.on("ended", () => {
      navigate("/");
      setOutgoingCall(false);
    });
    session.on("confirmed", () => {
      setOutgoingCall(false);
    });
    session.on("failed", () => {
      navigate("/");
      setOutgoingCall(false);
    });
    session.on("accepted", (e: any) => {
      attachIncommingLocalStream(session, "videoLocal");
      navigate("/answer");
    });
  };

  const inCommingCall = (session: RTCSession) => {
    console.log("inCommingCall session", session);
    session.on("progress", () => {
      setIncommingCall(true);
    });
    session.on("accepted", () => {
      navigate("/answer");
      setIncommingCall(false);
    });
    session.on("connecting", () => {
      console.log("inCommingCall call is in connecting ...");
    });
    session.on("confirmed", () => {
      attachIncommingLocalStream(session, "videoLocal");
      setIncommingCall(false);
    });
    session.on("ended", () => {
      setIncommingCall(false);
      navigate("/");
    });
    session.on("failed", () => {
      setIncommingCall(false);
    });
    session.on("peerconnection", (e) => {
      attachRemoteStream(e.peerconnection, "videoRemote");
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    sipClient?.on("newRTCSession", (data: RTCSessionEvent) => {
      const session: RTCSession = data.session;
      const direction = session.direction;
      console.log("direction", direction);
      setSession(session);
      if (direction === "incoming") {
        inCommingCall(session);
        // SessionDirection?.OUTGOING
      } else if (direction === "outgoing") {
        outgoingCall(session);
      }
    });
  }, [sipClient]);
```

The direction variable in the useEffect block gives me information about whether the call is incoming or outgoing, but I need to determine the call type (video or audio). Specifically, I want to identify whether an incoming call is a video call or an audio call.

Is there a way to extract this information from the JsSIP library? I have looked through the documentation, but I couldn't find a clear solution for this.

Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!